# setting up a brand new Magento installation for a merchant who is migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2

You are setting up a brand new Magento installation for a merchant who is migrating from Magento 1 to Magento 2.
Keeping in mind upgradability and the need to customize, which one do you choose?

- A. Create a new Magento instance using composer create-project
- B. Clone the magento/magento2 GitHub repository
- C. Run php bin/magento setup:migrate   command
- D. Create a new Magento instance by using the bin/magento install command

Can someone let me know what will be the correct answer with valid reason. I was thinking to go with C but then couldn't find this command in CLI commands list.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your workload.

you can create fresh project and migrate data or you can build magento then import data with csv.

anyway you need to run **A** + **D**

then you run **C** 
but you have to install `magento 2 data migration tool` first.

Comment: But I couldn't found the command mentioned in option C and this question has only one correct answer. Then what should be the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is **C**: Use a data migration tool.

For more details: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool.html

Answer (score 0):

C is not correct because to use the Data migration CLI its bin/magento migrate:  not bin/magento setup:migrate.

The Most likely answer is A. Keeping upgradability of dependencies in mind. And its also one of the requirements to use the Migration tool

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-preconditions.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-migrate.html